# Colocar popup apenas 1x a cada 24h por usuario

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando manipular o cookies aqui com javascript, to tentando colocar, que so  exibe o popups uma vez a cada 24h por usuário,  porem ele ta aparecendo toda hora que entro na página.

Aqui o meu código, onde estou errando? Minha lógica está errada ?

```
function checkLoading(e){
    d = new Date();
    document. cookie = "visto= true; expires = " + d.toUTCString() + ";path=/";
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1*24*60*60);

    if ( popupFormSubmitting == true ) {
        if(document.cookie == null){
            signupFormLoader.style.display = 'block'; 

        }
    }else{

        signupFormLoader.style.display = 'none'; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Não está de total errado a sua maneira de manipulação, mas seria melhor você fazer de uma maneira mais simples como esta:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("popupShown=true") == -1) {
    document.cookie = "popupShown=true; max-age=86400"; //86400: segundos em um dia
    // Faça o restante logo aqui abaixo
}
```

Sendo assim, após o cookie vencer (Depois dessas 24H), na próxima vez que a página carregar o popup irá aparecer! Veja direitinho na documentação do [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) para tirar demasiadas dúvidas ou deixe o comentário aqui caso haja mais dúvidas sobre o mesmo! :)

---

Já que o código anterior não funcionou com você, vamos tentar algo diferente... Segundo [esta reposta no Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12926206/4773947), você deve fazer desta maneira para que possa realmente definir/ler o seu cookie pelo JavaScript e adaptando para o que deseja:

```
function createCookie(name,value) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(3600*24));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

E uma vez feito isso, você basta adicionar isto:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var visto = readCookie('visto');
    if (!visto || visto !== "true") {
        createCookie('visto', "true");
        // Código do popup e demais códigos aqui
    }
});
```

Comment: não foi, o codigo não deu certo.

Comment: A função createCookie só admite dois parâmetros. Você está chamando-a com três. Pelo que entendi, o correto na declaração da função seria `function createCookie(name,value, expireDays)` E na linha do date.setTime fazer:  `date.setTime(date.getTime()+(expireDays*3600*24));`. Inclusive, é uma boa prática fazer `const MILLISECONDS_IN_A_DAY = 86400000` e reutilizar essa constante ao invés de usar a opção "hardcode" de fazer `3600*24`, digitando o valor diretamente. Seguindo essa recomendação, teríamos: `date.setTime(date.getTime()+(expireDays*MILLISECONDS_IN_A_DAY));`

Comment: Eu implementei em minha prévia resposta outra solução, se puder tentar! :)

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage) (LS), que também é um cookie. Basta você guardar no LS o [valor primitivo](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/ValueOf) da data atual e criar outra data adicionando +24 horas à data atual e depois fazer a comparação. Se o LS não existir mostra a popup e define o seu valor +24 horas. Se existir, faz a comparação, se for menor mostra a popup e redefine o tempo.

Considerando que o id da sua popup seja `#popup`, tipo:

```
<div id="popup">
  CONTEÚDO DA POPUP
</div>
```

Esconda a div da popup no CSS:

```
#popup{ display: none }
```

E ficaria assim toda a função:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

   // pega o elemento da popup
   var popup = document.getElementById("popup");

   // atribui o LS a uma vaviável
   var ls = localStorage.getItem("popup");

   // pega a data atual
   var data = new Date();

   // variável para guardar a data atual
   var data_atual = data.valueOf();

   // adiciona 24 horas à data atual
   var data24 = data.setHours(data.getHours()+24);

   // verifica se o LS é menor do que a data atual
   // ou se o LS for inexistente
   if(ls < data_atual){

      // mostra a popup
      popup.style.display = "block";

      // cria/redefine o LS com o nome "popup" com a data +24 horas
      localStorage.setItem("popup", data24);

   }

});
```

**Teste de 5 segundos:**

Como aqui no sandbox o LS não funciona, altere a linha:

```
var data24 = data.setHours(data.getHours()+24);
```

Para

```
var data24 = data.setSeconds(data.getSeconds()+5);
```

Faça reload na sua página dentro dos 5 segundos e verá que a popup não irá aparecer. Após 5 segundos ela irá aparecer 1 vez, e assim sucessivamente.

> Vou deixar abaixo o código enxuto sem comentários:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
   var ls = localStorage.getItem("popup");
   var data = new Date();
   var data_atual = data.valueOf();
   var data24 = data.setHours(data.getHours()+24);

   if(ls < data_atual){
      popup.style.display = "block";
      localStorage.setItem("popup", data24);
   }
});
```